# Excluding internal requests from Apache logs

Tags: logs, apache-httpd

I am running Apache2 on my Ubuntu server. There were tons of logs about Apache's internal requests for managing its child processes. It was filling the log file with lines like:

```
::1 - - [10/May/2015:23:16:31 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/May/2015:23:16:32 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/May/2015:23:16:33 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1f (internal dummy connection)"
```

So, I decided to exclude them and follow the instruction at [InternalDummyConnection](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection).

```
<VirtualHost *:80
  ...
  SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!loopback
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted Apache with the command `service apache2 restart`

I still get a log line every few seconds.

What's wrong? Should that line be placed out of VirtualHost definition?

Comment: Not to ask the obvious ... but did you restart the httpd service? Also, your remote address in this case is `::1` (IPv6) and the `SetEnvIf` is using `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) ... that difference might be of interest here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to define a **VirtualHost** section at the beginning of the config file to catch all requests on the loopback interface and send it to a different log file or not log it at all:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 [::1]:80>
        # catch local requests
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_local.log
        Loglevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_local.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was considering IPv6 as KM suggested.

I replaced those lines with:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" loopback
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!loopback
```